# Need MDX query for total count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, mdx

Last time I had posted a question which was a bit confused. But today I got the same question from my manager to get the MDX query.

Here is the scenario:

Fact Table

```
Ticket No / Ticket ID   
1           S   
2           S
3           S   
3           D   
4           D
```

Dimension Table

```
Ticket ID / [Count]
S           1
D           1
```

My manager said they are not using dimension table that they are not using just for understanding they have mentioned that. there is no use of considering it here.

So please ignore the Dimension table data.

The Output will be like this if we do group by based on Ticket ID:

```
Ticket ID / [Count]
S           3
D           2
```

If we do so we will get the total Count is

```
5
```

But I need the total count as 4 based on Ticket No.

Need help here.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, it seems to me the dimension table is irrelevant to the problem, no?

Comment: I have written a code SELECT [TIKCET NO], COUNT(*) as Total
FROM ABCD.DBO.FACTDIM GROUP BY [TIKCET NO] OR SELECT [TIKCET ID], COUNT(*) as Total FROM ABCD.DBO.FACTDIM GROUP BY [TIKCET ID]. But I am not getting the required data. I need the count 4 means the distinct of [ticket no].

Comment: That doesn't look like an MDX query. If you just want T-SQL how about `SELECT c = COUNT(DISTINCT [Ticket No]) FROM ABCD.dbo.FACTDIM;`?

Comment: I don't want tsql need MDX and frankly speaking I don't know how to write MDX Query. Just new to SQL. Your query in tsql is getting the write output but I am looking for MDX query with the same output.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an MDX guru. But perhaps you just need to add a distinct count as a measure?

Comment: not a problem Aaron. Really appreciate for your help.

Comment: Shahsra, what you have written above is an SQL query, not an MDX query. Did you say that the query you wrote returned values? In which case, you are working with SQL and not MDX.

Comment: Hey Sam, the written query above is not giving m exact but the Aaron sent me a query above is giving me right result  which I am looking for but that is in SQL and I need the same result in MDX query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My educated guess is that you're starting with OLAP/MDX. It's worth taking a bit of time reading in the web about MDX, something like [MDX Gentle Tutorial](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx_tutorial/gentle_introduction.html).

Without a dimension you can **not** have a cube. The minimum is one dimension and one measure in your facts.

In your case

```
 Ticket ID -> dimension with two possible values (S,D)
 Ticket No -> the measure, as Aaron pointed out. use unique count as aggregation type.
```

The MDX would looks like :

```
Select
 {[Ticked ID].allmembers} on 0,
 {[Measures].members on 1
from [MyCube]
```

We could find other ways of solving this but they would be certainly slower and more complicated.